# How do you add background music to SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, background-music

I tried doing this:

```
let soundFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GL006_SNES_Victory_loop.aif", ofType: "GL006_SNES_Victory_loop.aif")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath!)
let player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
player.numberOfLoops = -1 //infinite
player.play()
```

I put this code in the `didMoveToView` function, and I have `import AVFoundation` at the top of my code. I get the error:
`Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(Xcode 8 and Swift 3)**

Using SpriteKit this is pretty simple. You create an SKAudioNote with a sound file and then you attach it to your Scene as a child. It will loop by default:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let backgroundSound = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "bg.mp3")
    self.addChild(backgroundSound)
}
```

If you want to stop the background music at some point you can use the build in methods:

```
    backgroundSound.run(SKAction.stop())
```

Or maybe you want to play the sound again after stopping it:

```
    backgroundSound.run(SKAction.play())
```

SpriteKit makes this really simple. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, the parameter of type `NSErrorPointer` is left out and can be caught within `catch` block as follows:

```
do 
{
    let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
} 
catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error.description)
}
```

Addendum:

It is better to declare your `AVAudioPlayer` as an ivar; otherwise, it could be released and thus the music won't play:

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController 
{
    var player : AVAudioPlayer!

....
```

So, given that, we make a minor change to the aforementioned `try-catch`:

```
do 
{
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
} 
catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error.description)
}
```

***Edit:***

What you originally have:

```
let soundFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GL006_SNES_Victory_loop.aif", ofType: "GL006_SNES_Victory_loop.aif")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath!)
let player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
player.numberOfLoops = -1 //infinite
player.play()
```

Hereby adding the `catch` clause in Swift 2:

```
let soundFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GL006_SNES_Victory_loop.aif", ofType: "GL006_SNES_Victory_loop.aif")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath!)
do 
{
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
} 
catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error.description)
}
player.numberOfLoops = -1 //infinite
player.play()
```

Assuming your class is a subclass of `SKScene`:

```
class yourGameScene: SKScene
{
    //declare your AVAudioPlayer ivar
    var player : AVAudioPlayer!

    //Here is your didMoveToView function
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
         let soundFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GL006_SNES_Victory_loop.aif", ofType: "GL006_SNES_Victory_loop.aif")
         let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath!)
         do 
         {
             player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
         } 
         catch let error as NSError
         {
             print(error.description)
         }
         player.numberOfLoops = -1 //infinite
         player.play()

         //The rest of your other codes
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do i put the class and try-catch?

Comment: Hmmm... now I'm getting this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)` saying that `soundFilePath!` is `nil`.